# Rewriterule with redirect 301 and regexp not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got few issues with redirect 301 and rewriterule in htaccess.

I've got few thousands subpages with new links, which have to be redirected permamently, but I can manage it with 10-20 rewriterules. But not everything is going as it should be...

Basic rewriterule works just fine, example:

```
RewriteRule ^subpage-([0-9]+)*\.html$ subpage.php?p=$1 [L]
```

It gets me from subpage-1.html to subpage.php?p=1 (no 301 needed here, it's just example, rewriterule does it's job).

Simple rewriterule with 301 redirect also works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/subpage.php$ /subpage.html [L,R=301]
```

Althrough I don't know why I have to put "/" before "new-subpage". If I don't I'm being redirected to "domain/whole-ftp-path/new-subpage.html" and not "domain/new-subpage.html". Is it just redirect 301 thing?

And the main event:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/subpage.php?p=([0-9]+)$ /subpage-$1.html [L,R=301]
```

This does nothing, I'm getting domain/subfolder/subpage.php?p=1 with 404 (old subpages does not exist anymore in the same location).

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava it's in the main webpage folder, with index.php, etc - whole-ftp-path/webpage-folder/

Comment: OK can you place your full .htaccess here?

Comment: @anubhava `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.xx$

    RewriteRule ^subfolder/oldsubpage.php?p=([0-9]+)$ /newsubpage-$1-blabla.html [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^subfolder/oldsubpage.php$ /newsubpage.html [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^newsubpage.html$ newsubpage.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^newsubpage-([0-9]+)(-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))*\.html$ newsubpage.php?p=$1 [L]`

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `QUERY_STRING` in `RewriteRule`.

Replace your `.htaccess` with this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subfolder/oldsubpage\.php\?f=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newsubpage-%1.html? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+subfolder/oldsubpage\.php[\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newsubpage.html? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^subpage-([0-9]+)*\.html$ /subpage.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^newsubpag\.html$ /newsubpage.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks, almost there, but not quite yet. Instead of newsubpage-1.html I'm beig redirected to newsubpage-$%25.html. Typo? And why 302 and not 301?

Comment: There was a typo that I have fixed now. Once this is working you can replace 302 by 301. Better not to use 301 while in testing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with the query string. If you have only one subfolder you could try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule .*$ /subpage-%1.html [L,R=301]
```

With more subfolders you could try:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/subpage.php(.*)$ /subpage$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1-%1.html [L,R=301]
```